# Session is destroying after I close the tab - Socialite Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies, laravel-socialite

I have integrated laravel socialite in my project. When I login with FB using socialite and close the tab and re opens it then I have to do login process again. Is it destroying my session? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of the user then login with the id

```
Auth::loginUsingId($userID);
```

Comment: Hasan I want to login user with their email.

Comment: Hi, you can get the id of this user and login with it